# 'six' is not defined. requirements library issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I'm running the python script below on Google Cloud Functions and I have the following error:

`Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
name 'six' is not defined`

Here is my script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

def run(request):
    csv_file = six.BytesIO(b"""full_name,age
Phred Phlyntstone,32
Wylma Phlyntstone,29
""")

    table_ref = dataset.table('ga-online-audit:test_python.test')
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = 'CSV'
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        csv_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)  # API request
    job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
```

Here is my requirements txt file:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-logging
google-cloud-error-reporting
google-cloud-bigquery
six==1.13.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a dependency on six but you still need to import it in the script.

```
import six
six.BytesIO(...)
```